# cloc, how to sum the results?

Tags: java

Iam developing a program to analyze the source code of programs. Now, I'm having a trouble counting results, here comes my source code:

```
public void walk(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    int countFiles = 0;

    if (list == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getName());
            countFiles++;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            int count = 0;
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                count++;
                sc.nextLine();

            }
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(f);
            int lower = 0;
            int upper = 0;
            int digit = 0;
            int whiteSpace = 0;
            while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
                String str = sc2.nextLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                        lower++;
                    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                        upper++;
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                        digit++;
                    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) {
                        whiteSpace++;

                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Your code contains: " + count + " Lines!, Out of them:");
            System.out.println("lower case: " + lower);
            System.out.println("upper case: " + upper);
            System.out.println("Digits: " + digit);
            System.out.println("White Spaces: " + whiteSpace);

        }
        System.out.println("You have in total: " + countFiles);
    }

}
```

First question: when it comes to countFiles ( which is supposed to tell how many .java files or classes you have in your code) its counting and printing results like the following:
you have in total= 1 file
you have in total= 2 file
so how can i make it to print me the final result directly which is 2 in this case ?

Second question: how can I print the sum of the lines in the code in totally, instead of showing them for each class by it self?

Thanks

Comment: "First question" by moving the system.out outside the loop on file

Comment: "Second question": same stuff. Maybe you should read some tutorial on variables *scope*

Comment: @RC. I have tried to take it out, its giving a really wierd result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been solved by adding an if statment outside the for loop as the following:

```
     if(!(countFiles<=0) ){

                System.out.println("You have in total: " + countFiles);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the result of countFiles for every java file (it is inside your loop).  To print the final results, you need only print out countFiles after you've passed them all.

So simply move the statement outside the loop.

```
public void walk(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // ...
    int countFiles = 0;
    // ...

    for (File f : list) {
        // ...

        if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
            // ...
        }
        // System.out.println("You have in total: " + countFiles);
    }
    System.out.println("You have in total: " + countFiles);
}
```

The answer to your second question is really the same.  Move the statements outside the loop.

```
public void walk(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // ...
    int countFiles = 0;
    // ...

    int count = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int whiteSpace = 0;

    for (File f : list) {
        // ...

        // int count = 0;
        // int lower = 0;
        // int upper = 0;
        // int digit = 0;
        // int whiteSpace = 0;

        if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
            // ...
        }
        // System.out.println("You have in total: " + countFiles);
    }
    System.out.println("You have in total: " + countFiles);
    System.out.println("Your code contains: " + count + " Lines!, Out of them:");
    System.out.println("lower case: " + lower);
    System.out.println("upper case: " + upper);
    System.out.println("Digits: " + digit);
    System.out.println("White Spaces: " + whiteSpace);
}
```

Note that I moved the counters out of the loop because keeping track of results between loop passes requires that I have variables in the scope outside the code block.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I have moved countFiles print statement out of the loop, this is what am getting:

You have in total: 0
You have in total: 0
You have in total: 0
You have in total: 0
You have in total: 0
File:DiningPhilosophers.java
File:Philosopher.java
File:Table.java
You have in total: 3
You have in total: 0
You have in total: 0

Comment: Don't use my code as written.  I left a lot of it out.  Leave in the logic in that performs the calculation.

Comment: Of course not, all I did is that I moved the system out print statement out of the loop!

Comment: I just tried it.  It outputs once and they aren't zero.  Please note well the example above.  The declaration of the variables and the printout of those variables are *not* in any nested code blocks!

Comment: its strange why am still getting that wierd result! am I placing countFiles++ in the right place?

Comment: I can't know that!  I just know that the answer is correct.